# Windows 7 save dialog hang - any solutions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze

Far too often, the save dialog on some of my windows applications - notepad, paint, ms word etc hangs, and does not recover.

Due to this, the only option available is a kill, in which case data is lost for programs which do not automatically backup.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I searched on Google and various entries came up regarding users seeing this problem, but I did not find any resolution / patch for this.

**Did any of you hit this issue and fix it, or have any suggestions how I can get rid of the issue?**

Comment: Start by disabling any non-Microsoft extensions with [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). Also try to remove external drives to see whether they have influence. If none of the previous fix this, remove any virtual drive software as they are also in the explorer chain but not necessarily listed as a shell extension. And yes, [I did experience that last thing](http://forum.sysinternals.com/explorerexe-hangs-need-a-reboot_topic17735_page1.html)... :)

Comment: My first instinct is also external drives and Shell extensions.

Comment: I've been having similar problems but for most of the dialogs. I used ShellExView to disable the Image Resizer powertoy and to my surprise everything went back to normal.

Comment: Tom, that's a fantastic answer and pretty much the only one like it I could find on the internet with my Googling! Thank you! I had a misbehaving extension! I think you should post that as an answer rather than a comment! I don't remember issues like this in XP - seems like a pretty serious vulnerability to any program with a "Save As" menu item.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Save dialog hang issue and resolved it.  I used ShellExView utility and disabled the `Share-to-Web Upload Folder` extension. After that Save dialog opens normally.