# I can't save anything from Chrome/Flash Professional/FlashDevelop/Mozilla

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, freeze, flash

Every time I press `Ctrl + S` or right click and Save, Chrome freezes. And I have to restart it. That also happens to Mozilla/IE 10.

I don't know if it's related, but whenever I create a new .fla file in Adobe Flash Professional and I try to save it, Flash freezes.

That also happens in FlashDevelop. If I create a file and I save it, it freezes. My workaround for these was to copy an existent file, rename it and edit it the way I want. But I didn't find a workaround for the browsers.

(I restarted my PC, cleaned my registry with CCleaner, cleared the cache from the browsers - **nothing works**)

Comment: Please don't clean your registry.  It often does more damage.  In over 20 years in this filed, I have never solved a problem be solved, after using a registry cleaner.  Its much easier to remove the specific registry key manually.  Do these issues surface when you boot to Safe Mode?

Comment: The same thing happens in safe mode. I also did what it's suggested [here](http://superuser.com/questions/378296/windows-7-save-dialog-hang-any-solutions) to no avail. Using ShellExView, I left enabled only the ones that are from Microsoft, but the same thing happens.